# How to add Swagger.json in swagger UI

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi

I've created a swagger documentation but I don't know how to add a json file
[image]

I need to add similar link which redirects to the json document in new page

Answer (score 0):

You could put the swagger doc in the root directory.
[image]
Then map a same route as set to swagger endpoint.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("https://localhost:7040/mypath/swaggerDoc", "customSwagger");
});

app.MapGet("/mypath/swaggerDoc", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "swagger.json")));
});
```

Result
[image]